# What are the differences between gitlab flow with Release Branches and Microsoft's Release Flow?

Tags: git, branching-strategy

My team is transitioning from svn to git.
We are in the process of selecting a git workflow.

I appreciate that a lot of people use gitflow but it seems unnecessarily complicated to me.  I don't know why we would want a develop branch separate from master for instance.  And we only have bugs and features - not hotfixes etc.

I like the look of gitlab flow with Release Branches and Microsoft's Release Flow but I can't see what the difference is?
I'm assuming they must be different!

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#release-branches-with-gitlab-flow
http://releaseflow.org/

Comment: Is there anything in particular that is unclear to you?

Comment: Not really, if there are no appreciable differences it would make me wonder why they both exist.